# StoredProcedure working fast but SSRS working very slow

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I am using a stored procedure as a dataset in an SSRS report. Even though the stored procedure is running fast enough, the report is taking too long to process.
For the same set of parameters the stored procedure is giving result in 4-7 seconds but the SSRS report is taking around 4 minutes to pop up.
The data from coming from the stored procedure is big but not too big... its around 13k. Also I cant Implement grouping in Stored Procedure so I am grouping in the report itself. However, even after removing the grouping the performance got better merely (like 40 seconds less time).
Trying to figure out the issue and willing to discuss it as I am having similar issue with 2-3 reports.
Please, any help will be appreciated.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Monitor what's going on with Profiler.

Comment: SSRS is rarely as fast as the data engine at doing any kind of grouping and filtering. I *assume* that you're running the report on the SSRS instance, not on your PC (within SSDT). If so, does SSRS have sufficient resources available to it? I've seen too many Servers set up where the data engine has unlimited access to the server's resources (I.E.RAM), leaving poor SSRS with about 100MB to play with. If you're using SSDT, that isn't really a fair test, as the report is run using your PC's resources, not that of the server. @IvanStarostin not sure that'll help; SSRS is slow not the data engine.

Comment: If the report is deployed, check the execution log. This will tell you roughly where all the time it spent. It's more than likely the rendering that is taking the time. Here's a quick bit of SQL to get you started.  `SELECT 
    TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, TimeRendering, * 
    FROM ReportServer..executionlog l
        JOIN ReportServer..Catalog c on l.ReportID = c.ItemID
    WHERE c.name = 'MyReportName'
    ORDER By TimeStart Desc`

Comment: Well, the scenario I described above is when I am running the report in visual studio on my PC. When I am deploying it on the reporting server it becomes even more slower and takes around 5 minutes to pop up.

Comment: Normally you have slow(er) execution times in SSDT, as the server will have more resources than your PC will (and your PC's attention is split between a lot more applications). This implies, to me, that the resources available to the SSRS instance is tiny; so my suspicion that the data engine is using all the RAM, and other resources, is a good place to start looking. How much RAM does your server have, and what is the maximum RAM your Data Engine is allowed to use?

Comment: Parameter sniffing is the first & most likely possibility to investigate, see: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 0):

The way a stored procedure is written can affect the performance. from your description if you implement the second procedure below. i believe it will improve the performance.

SLOW Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROC SLOW_PROC (@ID INT)  
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
     ID 
    ,Name 
    FROM MyTable
WHERE ID =@ID
END
```

Fast stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC FAST_PROC (@ID INT)  
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NewID INT SET @NewID=@ID
  SELECT
     ID 
    ,Name 
    FROM MyTable
WHERE ID =@NewID
END
```

The difference may not be much but the performance is.
I hope this help

Comment: I have already coded the stored procedure in the similar manner and also stored procedure is fast like OK fast because its taking around 4-8 seconds..so that I guess is not a big problem.

Comment: @Larnu, I will have to check about the resource allocation for this and if that is the issue, I will do the necessary changes to satisfy the resource demand. But I want to know if any idea about improving the RDL while maintaining all the functionalities of report then that will be super awesome and I can make sure that the RDL is designed in the best way. So, any idea on this will be a great help and also very knowledge full for me. Thanks in advance!